# Cannot find Symbol .peek()

Tags: java, compiler-errors, queue

Hi so my I am trying to peek a queue but the compiler keeps throwing a cannot find symbol error.

```
public class HelloWorld{

interface Queue<T> {
Queue<T> enqueue(T ele);
T dequeue();
}

public static class QueueArray<T> implements Queue<T>{

    int top;
    private T[] arr;
    private int total, next;
    public int first;

    public QueueArray()
    {
        arr = (T[]) new Object[2];
        top = 0;
    }

    private void resize(int capacity)
    {
        T[] tmp = (T[]) new Object[capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++){
            tmp[i] = arr[(first + i) % arr.length];
        }

        arr = tmp;
        first = 0;
        next = total;
    }

    public QueueArray<T> enqueue(T ele)
    {
        if (arr.length == total) 
        {
            resize(arr.length * 2);
        }
        arr[next++] = ele;
        if (next == arr.length)
        {
            next = 0;
        }
        total++;
        return this;
    }

    public Object peek(){

        if(first > 0 ){
            return arr[first - 1];
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }

    }



    public T dequeue()
    {
        if (total == 0)
        {
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();

        }
        T ele = arr[first];
        if (++first == arr.length)
        {
            first = 0;
        }
        if(--total > 0 && total == arr.length/4) 
        {
            resize(arr.length/2);
        }
        return ele;

    }

} 


 public static void main(String []args){
   Queue<Integer> greeting = new QueueArray<>();

   greeting.enqueue(1).enqueue(2).enqueue(3);

   System.out.println(greeting.dequeue());
   System.out.println(greeting.peek());
   System.out.println(greeting.dequeue());
   System.out.println(greeting.dequeue());
   System.out.println(greeting.dequeue());

 }
}
```

I dont understand what is going go as when i call the .peek() it is spelled the same way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `Peek` method doesn't exist on your interface.

Comment: ah, thank you Im still pretty new to these things thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your queue instance is declared with the interface's type:

```
Queue<Integer> greeting = new QueueArray<>();
```

So the compiler will be looking at the interface, not the concrete `QueueArray` class, for the `peek` function when you call it.

So you need to add the `peek` method to the interface:

```
interface Queue<T> {
    Queue<T> enqueue(T ele);
    T dequeue();
    T peek();
}
```